# Trying to complete an ISNULL but get the error [BC30198] ')' expected

Tags: sql, isnull

I am getting the following error when trying to complete the query below.

> The Value expression for the textrun
>   ‘i_own_name.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error: [BC30198]
>   ')' expected.

Query is:

```
SELECT
,pi_appl_inspection.i_actual_date
,pi_appl_inspection.i_onsite_min
,pi_appl_inspection.a_location_unit
,pi_appl_inspection.i_own_name
,pi_appl_inspection.cplm_street_type
,pi_appl_inspection.a_inspect_desc
,ISNULL (pi_appl_inspection.a_inspect_desc, ISNULL(pi_appl_master.h_description1, pi_appl_inspection.i_own_name))AS EstablishmentName 

FROM
pi_appl_inspection
LEFT OUTER JOIN pi_appl_master
ON pi_appl_inspection.a_reference_no = pi_appl_master.a_reference_no AND pi_appl_inspection.i_parcel_id = pi_appl_master.a_parcel_id
```

Comment: are you sure that error has anything to do with this code?  That looks like a C# or java error not an SQL error.  SQL does now use array syntax like that.

Comment: This indeed does look like a code problem as opposed to a SQL problem.  That being said, you need to tag your questions better (we don't know if this is MS SQL, mySQL, oracle, etc.).  Also can you add the relevant code from the application (also be sure to tag that correctly as well, so people with expertise with that language can maybe have a shot of helping you out).  At a quick glance, my guess would be a syntax error on the code side, or some value that's expected to exist within a text box by your code that isn't there.

Comment: One thing I always do: start by running the SQL in a SQL editor instead of in your code. You want to make sure your SQL gives the results you want. Also, your code has "SELECT ,pi_..." That initial comma doesn't look like it belongs.

Answer (score 0):

If your query is correctly displayed above, in addition to WingedPanther73's response (the comma before the first selected row is out of place), there needs to be a space between the last parenthesis and the "AS". I think that might trigger the error.